# Run script on non-interactive SSH session (SFTP)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, login

I have a Linux development server in [Digital Ocean](https://m.do.co/c/9d90da6f0b8f) based on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. I use this mostly for development.

I created a script on /etc/profile.d/ to trigger an SMS message (based on Node.js via Twilio) to alert me whenever someone logs into the server on an interactive shell.

How do I do the same for non-interactive sessions? i.e.: If I use WinSCP to connect to the server and transfer files to/from the server, the script doesn't execute. I use Codeanywhere to code on my server, via SSH (SFTP), so ideally whenever I login via CodeAnywhere I'll get the same alert.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See my answer from this SF q&a https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way/274992

Comment: This way In addition you can do it this way “Ssh login alerts with sendmail and PAM” @alessandrocuda https://medium.com/@alessandrocuda/ssh-login-alerts-with-sendmail-and-pam-3ef53aca1381